# Encode a String in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I encode a string (iso to utf-8 for example) in Ruby on Rails, using Ruby 1.8.7 ?

Comment: 1.8 isn't encoding-aware, so you'd have to guess the encoding, and trust me, you don't want that. Upgrade to 1.9

Answer (score 5):

Use [toutf8](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/nkf/rdoc/String.html#method-i-toutf8) method.

```
"my string".toutf8
```

Comment: Use ICONV or Ruby 1.9 methods.